# Can Apache conditionally perform a rewrite from a custom http header?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have an apache server behind a (simple amazon) load balancer.  I want to redirect any incoming traffic that is not 443 to 443.  I would prefer it to use just one apache virtual host.  So I'm trying to detect that if the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT header is not 443.

I've checked the [RewriteCond docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) and it only works with a limited set of HTTP headers.

Basically what I'm doing is this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.example.com

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT} !=443
        RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

        ....
</VirtualHost>
```

But RewriteCond doesn't recognize HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT.

Is there any other way to accomplish this (with just one VirtualHost)?  (some type of incoming header check?)

Thanks, Lance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A little further down the `RewriteCond` document:

> `%{HTTP:header}`, where header can be any HTTP MIME-header name

So, you can do it, just not in quite the same form as the pre-extracted headers.

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Port} !=443
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Another example with an IP address in a header passed by SiteLock CDN: `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-For} !=123.45.67.89`